# How to write a repeatable raw_input?

Tags: python, raw-input

So I'm trying to write a script that allows a user to write down notes under different categories and then have those notes print to an output file. Heres a look at some example code.

```
def notes():
    global text
    text = raw_input("\nPlease enter any notes.\n>>> ")
    print "\Note added to report."
    notes_menu()

def print_note():
    new_report.write("\nNotes: \n%r" % text)
```

My question is in two parts:

1. What can I use to make this so that if the notes method gets called again(with text already being assigned to a string) it creates a new variable called text1 and will keep doing so as many times as the notes method is called and text is assigned?
2. How can I get the print method to keep checking, and printing as many text^nths as exist?

Comment: Use a `list` and append the input. Iterate over it to print. http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `list`s for that:

```
texts = []
def notes():
    global texts
    txt = raw_input("\nPlease enter any notes.\n>>> ")
    texts.append(txt) # Add the entered text inside the list
    print "\Note added to report."
    notes_menu()

def print_note():
    for txt in texts:
        new_report.write("\nNotes: \n%r" % txt)
```

I hope that is what you wanted.

EDIT: Since I am pretty sure I got downvoted because I used `global`, I would like to clarify: I used `global` because OP used `global`, not because that is a good solution.

Comment: @hedge_funder anyway, I would like to suggest that my answer has been tailored to let you understand what is happening (i.e. keeping it similar to your code), but *it is not* a good way to do it. In general, *avoid* to use globals, because they introduce side-effects that can be troublesome.

Answer (score 2):

Using

> iter(callable, sentinel) -> iterator

```
>>> list(iter(raw_input, ''))
apple
1 2 3
foo bar

['apple', '1 2 3', 'foo bar']
```

Customizing it:

```
>>> list(iter(lambda: raw_input('Enter note: '), ''))
Enter note: test
Enter note: test 2
Enter note: 
['test', 'test 2']
```

Comment: This is by far the most pythonic way to do it

Comment: I know, I just learned it myself. Raymond Hettinger talks about it in this pretty awesome [video](http://pyvideo.org/video/1780/transforming-code-into-beautiful-idiomatic-pytho) from this years pycon.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll want to use a loop to read multiple lines of notes, adding them to a list. Here's an example of how that might work:

```
def notes():
    lines = []
    print "Please enter any notes. (Enter a blank line to end.)"
    while True: # loop until breaking
        line = raw_input(">>> ")
        if not line:
            break
        lines.append(line)

    return lines
```